# Measuring KWh connecting to the mains

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I need to measure KWh of the mains, connecting something like a sensor to the mains and reading its value into analog. I already know to measure KWh from a KWh meter but I need to make my own.

Comment: You can put a current clamp around the wire, to measure the current. But you need to spit the live and neutral wires. Something you probably have to have an electrician done.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, what you want to do is measure the current consumed from the mains by whatever load is connected to it (Fan, AC, computer etc).

What you need is basically a current sensor, have a look at https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8883 and https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005

**Please understand that you are playing with the mains and unless you take the required precautions, you can get seriously injured**